# Handling Constants and variables in shell script

Tags: sql, performance, shell

I have the following code in my script. There are 50 more commands like this:

```
"SELECT date, count(*) FROM ttc_table....date_sub(current_date, **30**)" > **/path/location/file1.txt**
"SELECT date, count(*) FROM ascc_table....date_sub(current_date, **30**)" > **/path/location/file2.txt**
"SELECT date, count(*) FROM bmtc_table....date_sub(current_date, **30**)" > **/path/location/file3.txt**
```

I want to create constant for value 30 and have a variable for filepath.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/variables-and-substitution/ or search for "*bash variable substitution*" here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Arminius answers actually half of the question, the one about variables, and it is specific to *bash*.

Since you have tagged the question as *shell*, I assume that you are searching an answer which works on POSIX shells. This means:

(1) While many of the variable substitions explained in the document by Arminius work in POSIX shell too, be aware that not all do.

(2) You also asked about defining a constant. In POSIX shell, it is AFIK not possible to define a constant. If you really need this, you have to switch to a different shell - for instance Zsh or bash. Note that in these shells, constants are actually called *readonly variables*.